# How can I detect faces in images using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, face-recognition

I am using WPF application for photo gallery and I would like to add face recognition to my app.
Any suggestions to do that?

Answer (score 1):

WPF itself won't help yo at all: it's just a way of defining what happens in a Window. You would need to add code utilising a suitable Machine Learning library capable of detecting faces in photos.

I won't go into how the ML libraries need to be set up and trained, or how there might be one already suitably primed available (I don't know). That's a rather large subject and is nothing to do with *any* presentation layer technology.